# Is there a way to see which videos are not in an album in Vimeo?

Tags: vimeo

How can I see which videos have not been attached to an album? I can see a list of all my albums at http://vimeo.com/patelc75/albums. Also, is there a way to add more than 1 video to an album?

Answer (score 1):

To answer both questions:

1. Is it not possible to see which videos have not been added to any album.
2. You can add multiple videos to an Album from the Album's Settings page.
   `Album > Settings > Videos > Add more videos`